# Prevent winforms control from becoming visible when dynamically adding to Controls collection

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild

I have created a `Form` with a loading `Panel` on it.  The idea being that I want to show this loading panel until my dynamically created control is ready to display.

The loading `Panel` is visible initially, and then during the `OnShown` event I am creating my control and adding it to the page.  The reason I am using `OnShown` is that the `Form` is being used in an Mdi scenario so I need it to be fully displayed before I start loading the control (if I try this in the Load event then the Mdi Tab doesn't display until my control is loaded).

The problem is that there is noticable flicker which I believe is due to the fact that when I add my control to the `Controls` collection:

a) the Visible property is immediately set to true.
b) my control seems to appear in front of the loading Panel even though the z-index appears to be correct.

Here is the nub of the issue

```
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(loadingPanel.Visible); //true
        Debug.WriteLine(Controls.GetChildIndex(loadingPanel)); //0

        Debug.WriteLine(myControl.Visible); //false

        myControl.Visible = false;
        Controls.Add(myControl);
        //**

        Debug.WriteLine(myControl.Visible); //true

        Debug.WriteLine(Controls.GetChildIndex(loadingPanel)); //0
        Debug.WriteLine(Controls.GetChildIndex(myControl)); //1

        Debug.WriteLine(loadingPanel.Visible); //true

        base.OnShown(e);
    }
```

I was hoping that I could add my control to the collection and it would remain `Visible = false` so that I could set `Visible = true` when my control's Load event had completed.  Instead, my control comes into view and I get flickering.  Interestingly, if I don't set `loadingPanel.Visible = false` at any point then once my control has finished loading, the loadingPanel re-appears and hides my control.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could override the paint method and set a flag in your `OnShown` method, skipping any paint operations until the adding is complete. Just a stab in the dark!

Comment: @Charleh could you elaborate some more, it sounds like it could be something worth trying?  Perhaps in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat strangely, this is how I managed to solve my issue:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    //trigger the OnLoad event of myControl - this does NOT cause it to appear
    //over the loading Panel
    myControl.Visible = true;
    myControl.Visible = false;  //set it back to hidden

    //now add the control to the Controls collection - this now does NOT trigger the
    //change to Visible, therefore leaving it hidden
    Controls.Add(myControl);

    //finally, set it to Visible to actually show it
    myControl.Visible = true;

    base.OnShown(e);
}
```

I can only assume that when adding a control to the Control collection then if the handle is not created it will auto set it to Visible.  By making it visible before adding it to the collection, the relevant handles are created by do not affect the parent control.  Then when it is added to the collection later on, it still does not interfere with the parent control.

Answer (score 0):

I take it your `mycontrol` is a standard winforms control? Why not create a custom control with the desired `mycontrol` in it, and in that custom control, default the "child" control's visible property to false?

Have not tested this, but thats what I would do next...?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that my control is a custom UserControl.  I believe your suggestion would not change anything as the Controls.Add is will just set the Visible property to true on the control.

Comment: Yeah, but default your "child" controls to visible = false? Don't "set" it visible = false only before its loaded, have the child controls be visible = false by default? And set them to visible = true later?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the `Visible` that way, even when you set it to `false` successfully,  when you show them back, there is still some flicker if the number of controls is large. You should override the `OnLoad` method, and use `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` like this:

```
//Start adding controls
SuspendLayout();
//....

//in the OnLoad
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e){
  ResumeLayout(true);
}
```

I doubt that using `ResumeLayout(true)` right after finishing adding controls may be OK, you should also try that.